# Old jwt token does not expire and is still active on new requests

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, jhipster

I am testing the duration of the user session in a microservices structure with UAA JHipster that is responsible for OAuth2, when I access with the 'Remember me' option the token is updated every two minutes, however if I take an old request and use it on terminal with the `cUrl` command the old token remains active even though I logout the user. Should not the old token be invalid and prevent new requests after two minutes or after logout? Is it possible to invalidate the old token?

The application-dev.yml excerpt that directs the session parameters in the UAA looks like this:

```
uaa:
    key-store:
        name: config/tls/keystore.p12
        password: password
        alias: selfsigned
    web-client-configuration:
        # Access Token is valid for 2 mins
        access-token-validity-in-seconds: 120 
        # Refresh Token is valid for 7 days
        refresh-token-validity-in-seconds-for-remember-me: 604800
        client-id: web_app
        secret: changeit
```

Comment: You've discovered by JWT should never be used for authentication. Use oAuth, OpenAuth, Sessions or any other tech that is stateful. If you are not the influencer - pass this along to that person.  Read: http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using Oauth2 and Jwt, the UAA microservice is the OAuth2 service.

Comment: Ok, in that case, log in with your browser and see if you have two JSESSION cookies or just one. Then, log out of UAA and see if the "other" JSESSION cookie is retained.

Comment: After logging appears in cookies: access_token, session_token, XSRF and io;
When logging out it keeps the same tokens in the Cookie of the request headers.